# Add a character to a label C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, label, buttonclick

I am making a calculator app in WPF. On click of the 0 button it should add a 0. On click of the 1 button it should add a 1, and so on. I have used this code:

```
myLabel.Content = "0";
```

This changes the content to 0. When I put this on the 1 button and change the 0 to a 1, it removes the 0 and puts the 1 instead. How can I make it add to the label and not replace? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to get the current value of the Label's content, then append the character to it, then set that value to that string.

Comment: Try something like this: `myLabel.Content += newValue;`

Comment: @NateDev it's a simple view model with one property and one command but what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try initially as

```
 myLabel.Content="";
```

and then on click of button,

```
 myLabel.Content + = (New Value);
```

Comment: It will concatenate the string in the label instead of replacing it. That's what you're trying to do here, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

To add a 0 character to a string you can try this;

```
myLabel.Content += "0";
```

To and a 1 character use

```
myLabel.Content += "1";
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Use like this -

```
myLabel.Content += newValue;
```

Comment: So use myLabel.Content.toString() += newValue;

Comment: And how is this going to compile? You cannot set `Content.toString()`